# How to share constants between Interface Builder and the code?

Tags: iphone, interface, constants, builder

I wonder if there is a way to use constants in Interface Builder, in order to avoid manually setting the same color at different places for example (it could be a very tedious job sometimes...)

Currently I set the color in the code and use #define to setup the color, but obviously IB can't use #define...

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around this issue by subclassing the various controls to ensure the same style throughout the app. The drawback is that you can not see the style in interface builder only a wireframe.

For example I have a

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton 
@end


@implementation MyButton

 -(void) initialize{
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor MyButonColor]; // Using a category on UIColor
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)  {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to create a category on the UIColor class and create a class method on it. For example:

Place this in a header file (e.g. UIColor+CustomColors.h):

```
@interface UIColor ( CustomColors )
+ (UIColor *)myCustomColor;
@end
```

Place this in an implementation file (e.g. UIColor+CustomColors.m)

```
@implementation UIColor ( CustomColors )
+ (UIColor *)myCustomColor
{
   return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.5 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];
}
@end
```

Then you have access to the class method anywhere in your code like so:

```
...
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor myCustomColor];
...
```

See [Apple's documentation on Categories](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html) for more info.

Alternatively, you can save swatches of color through the system color palette. To do this you simply call up the system color palette, select a color and drag it into the grid of colors.

These colors are now available in not only every Interface Builder document you create, but any application that makes use of the system color palette.

[color palette http://img.skitch.com/20091030-dhh3tnfw5d8hkynyr7e5q3amwg.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091030-dhh3tnfw5d8hkynyr7e5q3amwg.png)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Actually, I would have liked to set the color in IB, not in the code (meaning that I want to avoid self.backgroundColor = myColor). But if I use a custom color from the color palette as you mention it, and if I want to modify in the future the percentage of blue of my color for instance, I still would have to do the change manually in IB everywhere the custom color is used... I'm keeping my #define solution for the moment, it saves me tedious refactoring time....